# Parse one JSON object with list to List in program

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

i have request to API with Retrofit2. API return one object, where there is a list with necessary info for me. How i can to have this list in my programm?

Answer (score 0):

With `Retrofit2` you define an interface and specify the request and response types. For example:

```
@POST("/api/myMethod")
public List<MyResponse> myMethod(@Body MyRequest myRequest);
```

Perhaps use that?

Answer (score 0):

Sample Json object  which having list of string

`{"list":["value1","value2","value3"]}`

So
Create class for this 
@POST("/url")
public Call> someMethod();

If you have some custom response rather than string

```
{"list":[
                 {"key":"value1","new":"item1"},
                 {"key":"value2","new":"item2"},
                 {"key":"value3","new":"item3"}
        ]
}
```

Then

```
class Sample{

@SerializedName("key")
String key;

@SerializedName("new") 
String new;
// add field which you want to handle
}
```

so response type will be

```
 @GET("url")
 Call<List<Sample>> someMethod();
```